# Is NoSQL 100% ACID 100% of the time?

Tags: nosql

Quoting: http://gigaom.com/cloud/facebook-trapped-in-mysql-fate-worse-than-death/

> There have been various attempts to
>   overcome SQL’s performance and
>   scalability problems, including the
>   buzzworthy NoSQL movement that burst
>   onto the scene a couple of years ago.
>   However, it was quickly discovered
>   that while NoSQL might be faster and
>   scale better, it did so at the expense
>   of ACID consistency.

Wait - am I reading that wrongly?

Does it mean that if I use NoSQL, we can expect transactions to be corrupted (albeit I daresay at a very low percentage)?

Comment: No - you didn't read it wrong...

Comment: See this: a handful support ACID (and JOINs). But yes, you have no guarantee of a successful write

Comment: for some problems you can do sharding. If the data usage patterns doesn't allow sharding, you basically have to answer one question: do you want ACID **or** do you want scalable?

Answer (score 7):

It's actually true and yet also a bit false. It's not about corruption it's about seeing something different during a (limited) period.

The real thing here is the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) which simply states you can only choose two of the following three:

1. Consistency (all nodes see the same data at the same time)
2. Availability (a guarantee that every request receives a response about whether it was successful or failed)
3. Partition
   tolerance (the system continues to operate despite arbitrary message loss)

The traditional SQL systems choose to drop "Partition tolerance" where many (not all) of  the NoSQL systems choose to drop "Consistency".

More precise: They drop "Strong Consistency" and select a more relaxed [Consistency model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) like "[Eventual Consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)".

So the data will be consistent when viewed from various perspectives, just not right away.

Comment: Even SQL databases can have eventual consistency. For eg - MySQL by default follows asynchronous replication. A read to a slave which doesn't have the latest change present can give you old data in response. CAP consistency is different from transaction inconsistency.

Answer (score 5):

NoSQL solutions are usually designed to overcome SQL's scale limitations. Those scale limitations are explained by the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).  Understanding CAP is key to understanding why NoSQL systems tend to drop support for ACID.

So let me explain CAP in purely intuitive terms. First, what C, A and P mean:

Consistency: From the standpoint of an external observer, each "transaction" either fully completed or is fully rolled back. For example, when making an amazon purchase the purchase confirmation, order status update, inventory reduction etc should all appear 'in sync' regardless of the internal partitioning into sub-systems

Availability: 100% of requests are completed successfully.

Partition Tolerance: Any given request can be completed even if a subset of nodes in the system are unavailable.

What do these imply from a system design standpoint? what is the tension which CAP defines?

To achieve P, we needs replicas. Lots of em! The more replicas we keep, the better the chances are that any piece of data we need will be available even if some nodes are offline. For absolute "P" we should replicate every single data item to every node in the system. (Obviously in real life we compromise on 2, 3, etc)

To achieve A, we need no single point of failure. That means that "primary/secondary" or "master/slave" replication configurations go out the window since the master/primary is a single point of failure. We need to go with multiple master configurations. To achieve absolute "A", any single replica must be able to handle reads and writes independently of the other replicas. (in reality we compromise on async, queue based, quorums, etc)

To achieve C, we need a "single version of truth" in the system. Meaning that if I write to node A and then immediately read back from node B, node B should return the up-to-date value. Obviously this can't happen in a truly distributed multi-master system.

So, what is the "correct" solution to the problem? It details really depend on your requirements, but the general approach is to loosen up some of the constraints, and to compromise on the others.

For example, to achieve a "full write consistency" guarantee in a system with n replicas, the # of reads + the # of writes must be greater or equal to n : r + w >= n. This is easy to explain with an example: if I store each item on 3 replicas, then I have a few options to guarantee consistency:

A) I can write the item to all 3 replicas and then read from any one of the 3 and be confident I'm getting the latest version B) I can write item to one of the replicas, and then read all 3 replicas and choose the last of the 3 results C) I can write to 2 out of the 3 replicas, and read from 2 out of the 3 replicas, and I am guaranteed that I'll have the latest version on one of them.

Of course, the rule above assumes that no nodes have gone down in the meantime. To ensure P + C you will need to be even more paranoid...

There are also a near-infinite number of 'implementation' hacks - for example the storage layer might fail the call if it can't write to a minimal quorum, but might continue to propagate the updates to additional nodes even after returning success. Or, it might loosen the semantic guarantees and push the responsibility of merging versioning conflicts up to the business layer (this is what Amazon's Dynamo did).

Different subsets of data can have different guarantees (ie single point of failure might be OK for critical data, or it might be OK to block on your write request until the minimal # of write replicas have successfully written the new version)

The patterns for solving the 90% case already exist, but each NoSQL solution applies them in different configurations. The patterns are things like partitioning (stable/hash-based or variable/lookup-based), redundancy and replication, in memory-caches, distributed algorithms such as map/reduce.

When you drill down into those patterns, the underlying algorithms are also fairly universal: version vectors, merckle trees, DHTs, gossip protocols, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean that transactions will be corrupted.  In fact, many NoSQL systems do not use transactions at all!  Some NoSQL systems may sometimes lose records (e.g. MongoDB when you do "fire and forget" inserts rather than "safe" ones), but often this is a design choice, not something you're stuck with.

If you need true transactional semantics (perhaps you are building a bank accounting application), use a database that supports them.

Answer (score 1):

First, asking if NoSql is 100% ACID 100% of the time is a bit of a meaningless question.  It's like asking "Are dogs 100% protective 100% of the time?"  There are some dogs that are protective (or can be trained to be) such as German Shepherds or Doberman Pincers.  There are other dogs that could care less about protecting anyone.

NoSql is the label of a movement, and not a specific technology.  There are several different types of NoSql databases.  There are document stores, such as MongoDb. There are graph databases such as Neo4j.  There are key-value stores such as cassandra.

Each of these serve a different purpose.  I've worked with a proprietary database that could be classified as a NoSql database, it's not 100% ACID, but it doesn't need to be.  It's a write once, read many database.  I think it gets built once a quarter (or once a month?) and then is read 1000s of time a day.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a lot of different NoSQL store types and implementations.** Every of them can solve trade-offs between consistency and performance differently. The best you can get is a **tunable** framework.

Also the sentence **"it was quickly discovered"** from you citation is plainly stupid, this **is no surprising discovery but a proven fact with deep theoretical roots**.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not that any given update would fail to save or get corrupted -- these are obviously going to be a very big issue for any database.

Where they fail on ACID is in data retrieval.

Consider a NoSQL DB which is replicated across numerous servers to allow high-speed access for a busy site.

And lets say the site owners update an article on the site with some new information.

In a typical NoSQL database in this scenario, the update would immediately only affect one of the nodes. Any queries made to the site on the other nodes would not reflect the change right away. In fact, as the data is replicated across the site, different users may be given different content despite querying at the same time. The data could take some time to propagate across all the nodes.

Conversely, in a transactional ACID compliant SQL database, the DB would have to be sure that all nodes had completed the update before any of them could be allowed to serve the new data.

This allows the site to retain high performance and page caching by sacrificing the guarantee that any given page will be absolutely up to date at an given moment.

In fact, if you consider it like this, the DNS system can be considered to be a specialised NoSQL database. If a domain name is updated in DNS, it can take several days for the new data to propagate throughout the internet (depending on TTL configuration).

All this makes NoSQL a useful tool for data such as web site content, where it doesn't necessarily matter that a page isn't instantly up-to-date and consistent as long as it is reasonably up-to-date.

On the other hand, though, it does mean that it would be a very bad idea to use a NoSQL database for a system which does require consistency and up-to-date accuracy. An order processing system or a banking system would definitely not be a good place for your typical NoSQL database engine.

Comment: What most NOSQL databases are definitely not good at is ad-hoc queries. For something like order processing system, they are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

NOSQL is not about corrupted data. It is about viewing at your data from a different perspective. It provides some interesting leverage points, which enable for much easier scalability story, and often usability too.  However, you have to look at your data differently, and program your application accordingly (eg, embrace consequences of BASE instead of ACID). Most NOSQL solutions prevent you from making decisions which could make your database hard to scale.

NOSQL is not for everything, but ACID is not the most important factor from end-user perspective. It is just us developers who cannot imagine world without ACID guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading that correctly. If you have the AP of CAP, your data will be inconsistent. The more users, the more inconsistent. As having many users is the main reason why you scale, don't expect the inconsistencies to be rare. You've already seen data pop in and out of Facebook. Imagine what that would do to Amazon.com stock inventory figures if you left out ACID. Eventual consistency is merely a nice way to say that you don't have consistency but you should write and application where you don't need it. Some types of games and social network application does not need consistency. There are even line-of-business systems that don't need it, but those are quite rare. When your client calls when the wrong amount of money is on an account or when an angry poker player didn't get his winnings, the answer should not be that this is how your software was designed.

The right tool for the right job. If you have less than a few million transactions per second, you should use a consistent NewSQL or NoSQL database such as VoltDb (non concurrent Java applications) or Starcounter (concurrent .NET applications). There is just no need to give up ACID these days.